# Changing the color of the starting screen

Tags: swiftui

I am developing a SwiftUI app that uses its own color scheme and does not use the `.light` or `.dark` schemes.

Every time it launches, a white screen shows for one second or two, while the app loads, before showing my app first screen.

Is there a way to change this to another color?

I have tried:

```
ContentView()
  .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
```

I have also tried these changes in the info.plist and adding a color called `backgroundColor` and a black image to `Assets.xcassets`.

[image]

No difference at all. Still white.

Comment: Setting "Image Name" in Info.plist worked for me. Do note that the image's original size is used, so you shouldn't use a small image if you want to cover the whole screen. That said, setting "background color" doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was hiding in plain view!

The change has to be done on the App struct.

```
var body: some Scene {
  WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
      .background(Color.black)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to change is the launch screen. Depending on your project you either do that with an image or more probably in the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file that gets created automatically when you start a new project with Xcode.

Follow Apple's instructions to create a launch screen: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/specifying-your-apps-launch-screen/

Comment: Thanks but I am asking about SwiftUI.... no storyboards there.

Comment: Yes, however launch screens are a different topic. I edited my answer to include a link to the documentation by Apple on how to create a launch screen. A launch screen is the view that gets shown while the app is loading. Meaning in that time you won't see the app's views itself, but only the launch screen. And this screen can't be implemented with SwiftUI yet.

Comment: you forgot the link...

Comment: @Duck look at my answer on top :) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/specifying-your-apps-launch-screen/

Comment: Thanks but I stumbled on the correct answer by a wild guess.